Can you ever obtain a pure rotation from composing Lorentz transformations?
An exercise asks one to show that given $v, u$ speeds much smaller than $c$ and oriented orthagonally, the composition of the lorentz boosts $B(\mathbf{v})B(\mathbf{u})B(\mathbf{-v})B(\mathbf{-u})$ is a rotation, and find the angle and direction of rotation.
Let $B(\mathbf{v})B(\mathbf{u})$ be written as $R(\mathbf{\epsilon})B(c\mathbf{a}/\gamma)$, and $B(\mathbf{-v})B(\mathbf{-u})$ as $B(-c\mathbf{b}/\gamma)R(\epsilon)$. Then the full product is $R(\mathbf{\epsilon})B(c\mathbf{a}/\gamma)B(-c\mathbf{b}/\gamma)R(\epsilon)$. If this is a pure rotation, then $B(c\mathbf{a}/\gamma)B(-c\mathbf{b}/\gamma)$ has to be a pure rotation, I don't see why this is.
Is the rotation aspect here the result of an approximation? In general, can you produce pure rotation through a product of boosts?(edit: yes from naturallyInconsistent's answer)


Doing it via. bruteforcing the matrix, I took the frame where $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{u}$ are aligned with the x and y axis respectively and got the following matrix for the spatial part of the transformation. Indeed $\mathbf{e_z}$ is an eigenvector and seems to be the axis of rotation, but I couldn't seem proceed to simplify it as
$\gamma_v^2(1-\gamma_u^2v)$ goes to $1+v$ whilst $\gamma_u^2(1-\gamma_v^2u)$ goes to $1+u$ for small $u$, $v$.
\begin{bmatrix}
    \gamma_v^2(1-\gamma_u^2v) & \gamma_v\gamma_uvu(\gamma_v+\gamma_u-\gamma_v\gamma_u) & 0 \\
    -\gamma_v\gamma_uvu & \gamma_u^2(1-\gamma_v^2u) & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
I am trying to find a $\theta$ s.t. this is equal to
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) & 0\\
\sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
Is this what one would usually look for?

Errm, what prevents you from trying $B(\vec v)B(\vec u)B(-c\vec a/\gamma)$ and thereby obtain a pure rotation?

I always thought of boosts AS rotations between spatial-temporal dimensions

It would be helpful if you use consistent ($v_1, v_2$) notation and explain symbols such as a,b,M.

The claim is correct: the listed composition of boosts will in general produce a rotation. If you think otherwise, you need to produce your working is a lot more detail than you are currently doing. As things stand, it's impossible to explain in any more detail why the claim does work.

Related : (1) Show that any proper homogeneous Lorentz transformation may be expressed as the product of a boost times a rotation.(2)  General matrix Lorentz transformation.

Ever? Always, of course, for infinitesimal boosts.
Review your Wigner rotations but consider the evidently superior 2$\times$2 matrix representation of the spinor map, which protects you from the busy 4×4 matrix confusions you appear to be laboring under. Utilize rapidities,
$$
\vec u = c \hat x \tanh \zeta, \qquad \vec v = c \hat y \tanh \xi,
$$
so, for all boost speeds/rapidities, you just have the group commutator
$$
B(\vec v)B(\vec u)B(-\vec v)B(-\vec u)= e^{\xi \sigma_2/2} e^{\zeta \sigma_1/2}e^{-\xi \sigma_2/2}e^{-\zeta \sigma_1/2}.
$$
The equivalent of this is worked out explicitly in this answer,
but for small rapidities this collapses to a triviality, necessarily the algebra commutator augmenting the identity; to lowest (quadratic) non vanishing order, it is but
$$
(1+\xi \sigma_2/2 +...) (1+\zeta \sigma_1/2 +...)(1-\xi \sigma_2/2 +...)(1-\zeta \sigma_1/2 +...)\\ = 1+ \zeta \xi ~i\sigma_3/2+...
$$
a small rotation around the $\hat z$ axis by an angle $\zeta \xi$.
Now, utilizing the linked answer,
you can always arrange that
$$
B(-c \tanh\! f ~~(\hat{x} \cos\phi +\hat{y} \sin\phi))~B(\vec v)B(\vec u) = R(\theta \hat z),
$$for finite rapidities, without any approximations. $\phi$, θ and f are the functions of v and u specified there.

Thank you for your response, I am not familiar with this language but I will take a look. What is meant by "general, finite, formulas"?

I clarified the finite formula statement. The finite group commutator is not a rotation, but utilizing the linked answer, as suggested by @naturallyInconsistent, you may get a pure rotation.

You may stick to  4x4 notation, if you wish...
